# Don't show any error but code does not works

Tags: javascript

I m learning javascript from youtube I have coded as the instructor coded.
But its not same or code is not working.

I have listed html and js code. Please can anyone tell me what is wrong.

Youtube link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wc5k2AMPED0

```
 <form>
    <div class="field-name">
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="">
        <div id="addhere"></div>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="field-email innactive">
        <i class="fal fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="field-password innactive">
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="field-finish innactive">
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
        <p>Thank you</p>
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    </div>

</form>

function animatedForm(){
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-arrow-down");
arrows.forEach(arrow =>{
    arrow.addEventListener("click", () =>{
        const input = arrow.previousElementSibling;
        const parent = arrow.parentElement;
        const nextForm = parent.nextElementSibling;
        if(input.type === "text" && validateUser(input)){
            console.log("everything is okay");
        }
    });

});
}

function validateUser(user){
    if(user.value.length < 6){
        console.log("not enough character");
        error("rgb(189,87,87)");
    }
    else{
        error("rgb(87,87,130)");
        return true;
    }
}


function error(color){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
animatedForm();
```

No any error on console :(.

Comment: put javascript code inside `<script></script>` tag

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar true

Answer (score 1):

were you supposed to place the javascript block within `script` tags?

```html
<form>
    <div class="field-name">
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="">
        <div id="addhere"></div>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="field-email inactive">
        <i class="fal fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="field-password inactive">
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="field-finish inactive">
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
        <p>Thank you</p>
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    </div>

</form>

<script>
function animatedForm(){
    const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-arrow-down");
    arrows.forEach(arrow =>{
        arrow.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            const input = arrow.previousElementSibling;
            const parent = arrow.parentElement;
            const nextForm = parent.nextElementSibling;
            if(input.type === "text" && validateUser(input)){
                nextSlide(parent,nextForm);
            }
        });
    });
}

function validateUser(user){
    if(user.value.length < 6){
        console.log("not enough character");
        error("rgb(189,87,87)");
    }
    else{
        error("rgb(87,87,130)");
        return true;
    }
}

function nextSlide(parent, nextForm){
    parent.classList.add('inactive');
    parent.classList.remove('active');
    nextForm.classList.add('active');
}


function error(color){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
animatedForm();
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention i have separate file for js.
And also i have edited my js code just to log "everything is okay" if code works.

can you please look at it once again.

Thank you.

Comment: In that case, have you included the said js file with a script tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code should be inside `<script></script>` tag... And also, missed the `CSS Styles` and `Font-awesome`.